# Eloquent Nested Relationship Returning null while using SELECT statement

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I'm using Slim with Eloquent and I've met something wried that nested relationship returning null while selecting specific columns.
My code looks like this:

```
class User extends Model {}
class Task extends Model {
    public function publisher() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'published_by');
    }
}
class Package extends Model {
    public function task() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Task', 'task_id');
    }
}
```

And something strange happened:

```
// Works well, I got publisher info and task info, but some columns are useless
// I just want to hide them and (may) improve performance in this case
Package::with('task.publisher:id,nick')->get();
// I got a null publisher
Package::with('task:id,title', 'task.publisher:id,nick')->get();

// Error: Unknown column `publisher`
Package::with('task:id,title,publisher')->get();
Package::with('task:id,title,publisher:id')->get();
```

How could I get a `Package` model with its `Task` and `Task's` publisher (which is a `User` model while only specific columns of `Task` and `User` are returned?
Thanks there.

Comment: You can answer your own question. Put the respected part of your post in the answer section. And than accept it as an answer.

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, due to some reason I haven't check the notifications these days, now I know the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solution by OP.*

I guess that selecting the specific column of `Task` cause `Task.published_by` to `null` so that no `User` can be queried by `publisher()`. The solution is shown below:

```
// This works well
Package::with('task:id,title,published_by', 'task.publisher:id,nick')->get()
```